# How to obtain elements of dihedral group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

I'd like to obtain a list of all permutations contained in `D_n` using GAP.
E.g. for `D_8` I've tried the following:

```
gap> G := DihedralGroup(8);
<pc group of size 8 with 3 generators>
gap> List(G);
[ <identity> of ..., f3, f2, f2*f3, f1, f1*f3, f1*f2, f1*f2*f3 ]
```

How can I obtain a list of actual permutations contained in `D_8` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you could try this:

```
gap> D_8:=DihedralGroup(IsPermGroup,8);
Group([ (1,2,3,4), (2,4) ])
gap> Elements(D_8);
[ (), (2,4), (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3,4), (1,3), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4,3,2), (1,4)(2,3) ]
```

You can find further information about `IsPermGroup` [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap43.html#X85ED46007CED6191)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: More generally, you can use `Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(G))` to find a permutation representation of a group G, and then get its elements. See also  http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/01-command-line/ for further pointers to `AsSSortedList` and `AsList`. Also, accidentally this question is now shown as 400th question under the `gap` tag!